field validation problem returns error with type
I have a problem with pol validation in the following screenshots I show you my problem.  If the scheme is less than zero, it should return an error, but I don't know why it doesn't work and returns these errors
enter image description here


Code Website
@page
@using System.Web
@model WebApplication3.Pages.Declarations.EditableDeclarationLineModel
@{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/form.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/details.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/table.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans&display=swap">
}
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edytuj wiersz deklaracji";
}

<script>

    }
    function getAmountFin(Amount) {
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "?handler=ValidateDataVar2&Amount=" + Amount + "&VarNo=" + document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect").value,
            success: function (data) {

                var SowingDate = new Date(document.getElementById('SowingDateInput').value);
                var SDm = SowingDate.getMonth() + 1;
                var SDd = SowingDate.getDay();
                const myArr = JSON.parse(data);
                const month = myArr[0];
                const day = myArr[1];
                if (month > SDm || isNaN(SDm)) {
                    var KGRate = document.getElementById('KGRate').value.replace(",", ".");
                    var AmountMat = document.getElementById('AmountOfMaterials').value.replace(",", ".");
                    var number = parseFloat(KGRate * AmountMat);
                    document.getElementById('Amount').value = number.toLocaleString("pl-PL");
                }
                else {
                    if (day >= SDd & month == SDm) {
                        var KGRate = document.getElementById('KGRate').value.replace(",", ".");
                        var AmountMat = document.getElementById('AmountOfMaterials').value.replace(",", ".");
                        var number = parseFloat(KGRate * AmountMat);
                        document.getElementById('Amount').value = number.toLocaleString("pl-PL");
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('Amount').value = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    function PlantsVarietyList(GrainKind) {
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "?handler=VarietyDropDownList&GrainKind=" + GrainKind + "&id1=" + document.getElementById("id1").value + "&TypeSowing=" + document.getElementById("TypeOfSowing").value,
            success: function (data1) {
               
                if (document.getElementById("GrainKind") != null) {
                    document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect").removeAttribute("readonly");
                    document.getElementById("AreofLond").removeAttribute("readonly");

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect").setAttribute("readonly", true);
                    document.getElementById("AreofLond").setAttribute("readonly", true);
                }
                removeOptions(document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect"));
                var x = document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = "-- Wybierz odmianę --";
                option.className = "left-align-option";
                x.add(option);

                data1.forEach((obj) => add1(obj));
                ;
            }
        })
    }
    function add1(obj) {
        var x = document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = obj.text;
        option.setAttribute("value", obj.value);

        x.add(option);

    }
    function removeOptions(selectElement) {
        var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
        for (i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
            selectElement.remove(i);
        }
    }
    function makeFieldEditable(TypeOfSowing) {
        var result = null;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "?handler=ValidateDataVar3&TypeOfSowing=" + document.getElementById("TypeOfSowing").value + "&id1=" + document.getElementById("id1").value,
            success: function (data1) {
                removeOptions(document.getElementById("GrainKind"));
                var x = document.getElementById("GrainKind");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = "-- Wybierz gatunek odmiany --";
                option.className = "left-align-option";
                x.add(option);

                data1.forEach((obj) => add2(obj));

                removeOptions(document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect"));
                var x = document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect");
                var option = document.createElement("option");
             
                document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect").
                option.text = "-- Wybierz odmianę --";
                option.className = "left-align-option";
                x.add(option);

                data1.forEach((obj) => add1(obj));
                document.getElementById("VarietyNoSelect").readOnly = true;
            }
        })
    }
    function add2(obj) {
        var x = document.getElementById("GrainKind");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = obj.text;
        option.setAttribute("value", obj.value);

        x.add(option);

    }
    function makeFieldEditable2(SowingDate) {
        if (SowingDate != null) {
            document.getElementById("AmountOfMaterials").removeAttribute("readonly");
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    .left-align-option {
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<div class="head">
    <a asp-page="./DeclarationsList"><img style="transform: rotate(90deg);" src="~/image/strzalka2.png" /></a>
    <div class="Title-Home">Strona główna- Szczegóły deklaracji- Edytuj siew </div>
    <div>
        <b class="Title">Edytuj siew</b>
    </div>
</div>
<p>@Model.DocNo</p>
<form class="FormCreateDecLine" method="post">
    <div id="general-data">
        <div class="form-information">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-groupAddSowing">
                <label class="control-label" >Rodzaj siewu</label>
                <select asp-for="AgnasLine.TypeofSowing" class="FormSelectDeclar" asp-items="@Model.TypeOfSowing"  id="TypeOfSowing" onchange="makeFieldEditable(this.value)" >
                    <option value=""> Wybierz rodzaj siewu </option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.TypeofSowing" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-groupAddSowing" hidden=true>
                <label class="control-label">Nr odmiany</label>
                <input asp-for="AgnasLine.Variety" class="FormControlDeclar" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.Variety" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-groupAddSowing">
                <label class="control-label">Gatunek</label>
                <select asp-for="AgnasLine.GrainKind" class="FormSelectDeclar" data-val="false" id="GrainKind" asp-items="@Model.GrainKind" onchange="PlantsVarietyList(this.value)" autofocus required title="To pole jest wymagane.">
                    <option value="">-- Wybierz rodzaj ziarna --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.GrainKind" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-groupAddSowing">
                <label class="control-label">Nazwa odmiany</label>
               
                @* <select asp-for="AgnasLine.VarietyNo" class="FormControlDeclar" asp-items="@Model.VarietyName" id="VarietyNoSelect" onchange="getAmount(this.value)">
                <option value="">-- Wybierz odmianę --</option>
                </select>*@
                <select asp-for="AgnasLine.VarietyNo" class="FormSelectDeclar" id="VarietyNoSelect" data-val="false" asp-items="@Model.VarietyName" onchange="getAmount(this.value)" readonly autofocus required title="To pole jest wymagane.">
                    <option>Nazwa odmiany</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.VarietyNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-groupAddSowing" id="SowingDate" hidden>
                <label class="control-label" >Data siewu</label>
                <input asp-for="AgnasLine.SowingDate" class="FormControlDeclar" id="SowingDateInput" onchange="makeFieldEditable2(this.value)" placeholder="Data siewu" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.SowingDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-groupAddSowing">
                <label class="control-label">Ilość materiału ze zbioru kg</label>
                <input asp-for="AgnasLine.AmountOfMaterials"  class="FormControlDeclar" formnovalidate id="AmountOfMaterials" placeholder="Ilość materiału ze zbioru kg" min="0,01" data-val="true" data-val-range="Wartość musi być większa niż 0." data-val-required="To pole jest wymagane." onchange="getAmountFin(this.value)" autofocus required title="To pole jest wymagane." />
                <span asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.AmountOfMaterials" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-groupAddSowing">
                <label class="control-label">Powierzchnia obsiana ha</label>
                <input asp-for="AgnasLine.TheAreaOfLandPlanted" class="FormControlDeclar" data-val="false" id="AreofLond" placeholder="Powierzchnia obsiana ha"  autofocus required title="To pole jest wymagane." />
                <span asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.TheAreaOfLandPlanted" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

the assumption of the project is that it should return an error when entering a value of zero or less than zero, therefore in the code it uses data-val and the error is when I have 2 decimal places and if I have 3 the system lets me through, I don't know why
whereas if I add to this value to class AgnasLine
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
[Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The value must be greater than 0.")]
then I won't be able to receive a document from another platform that sends data to the page with a value of 0

how AmountOfMaterials property is defined in model (with all attributes)

there is no definition, it can't be because there is data coming into my site and there can be a value of 0

So in your c# code there is no class with this AmountOfMaterials property... Interesting... How this even compile...

asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.AmountOfMaterials" -> points to that this view using a model named AgnasLine, you might find a class which name is AgnasLine in your application or other reference lib, then inside this class, it should define a property AmountOfMaterials. Normally speaking.... See tag helper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0  asp-for is a tag helper and it do validation in server side.

I also noticed that you are using data-val-range, which doing validation in the client side. Could you please share more codes with us and let us know what you are trying to achieve? Doing validation via jquery in the client or asp.net core in server side?

hi @TinyWang it depends what you want to see when it comes to data-val, I use it to return an error when the value is zero and less than zero. However, I didn't want it in the AgnasLine class because data with a value of zero can come to the page and if I limit it in the class I can't accept such data.

sorry I can't understand well.. asp-validation-for="AgnasLine.AmountOfMaterials" is used when we submit form. For example, we add limitation for property AgnasLine.AmountOfMaterials to only accept int and > 0, then we are able to enter -1 into the input, but when we click submit button and submit form data to the controller, the validation worked and will return back to view and display validation error message. So that I can't understand your issue well.... Could you please let us know the whole story? What's the page, how it display data and operate data, etc..

I have added the code in a post that you can check out

this page is used to create data on the website

to be honest, i can't understand your requirement now. asp-validation-for is used when the form is submited, but you didn't share the post request endpoint, nor the model you used. If you want to make that property to only allow number we might just try [Required] [Range(0,100)] public int AmountOfMaterials { get; set; }

To solve the problem I used aria-invalid and javascript, which made the validation to work
javascript
function CheckValidation(){
    var AmountofMatertial = document.getElementById('AmountOfMaterials');
    var AmountofMat = document.getElementById('AmountOfMaterials').value.replace(",", ".");
    var TheAreaOfPlantes = document.getElementById('AreofLond');
    var TheAreOfPlan = document.getElementById('AreofLond').value.replace(",", ".");
    visible=true;
    if (AmountofMat <= 0) {
        AmountofMatertial.setAttribute('aria-invalid', true);
        visible=false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        AmountofMatertial.setAttribute('aria-invalid', false);
    }
    if (TheAreOfPlan <= 0) { 
        TheAreaOfPlantes.setAttribute('aria-invalid', true);
        visible=false;
    }
    else{
        
        TheAreaOfPlantes.setAttribute('aria-invalid', false);
    }
    return visible;
}

html
    <input asp-for="AgnasLine.AmountOfMaterials" class="FormControlDeclar" formnovalidate id="AmountOfMaterials" aria-invalid="false" aria-errormessage="err1" placeholder="Ilość materiału ze zbioru kg" data-val="false" onchange="getAmountFin(this.value)" autofocus required title="To pole jest wymagane." />
     <span id="err1" class="errormessage">Wartość musi być większa niż 0.</span>
               


